# Button inside of div, not to send div onclick - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

I have a div, and that div has an onclick event. Inside of the div, there is some text, and a button. When I click on the text, the div onclick is sent, which is good. However, when I click in the button inside of the div, the onclick for the button **and** the div are sent. I know that this is meant to happen, but I need it to not happen. Is there any way, **without** using jQuery, to not send off the div onclick, when the button is pressed?

[Here is a jsFiddle of my current program](http://jsfiddle.net/aMfbk/)

```
<div onclick="divClick()">
This is the div
<button name="test" onclick="buttonClick()">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

**I really do not want to use jQuery, just pure JavaScript**

Answer (score 9):

Use **[stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/event.stopPropagation)** event function. This way `divClick` function will not be called.

```
function buttonClick(e) {
   if (!e) e = window.event;
   e.stopPropagation();
   // do what you want
}
```

Because of Firefox you need to explicitly send `event` as argument like this:

```
<button name="test" onclick="buttonClick(event)">Click Me</button>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aMfbk/3/)**

Comment: That doesnt work: http://jsfiddle.net/yNRdp/ - the "button clicked" doesnt show up

Comment: Interesting, why does it work in one fiddle and not the other?

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I needed! Can you explain to me what the e is for?

Comment: @Rikard your fiddle has `onclick="buttonClick(e)"`. It should just be `onclick="buttonClick()"`, without the argument.

Comment: `e` is the event object. calling `stopPropagation` prevents further DOM propagation and thats why `divClick` function is not called.

Comment: @Rikard your fiddle shows onclick="buttonClick(**e**)" You do not want the **e**

Comment: @ThomasUpton, it does not work without the e either, I wonder why. I cannot answer my self... http://jsfiddle.net/yNRdp/1/

Comment: Your fiddle runs both functions on button click in firefox. Any idea why? http://jsfiddle.net/aMfbk/2/

Comment: @Rikard yes. In Firefox you have to explicitly send `event` as argument. see updated answer

Comment: @Rikard With the argument passed as `e` in the `onclick` attribute, the click handler for the `div` gets triggered in Chrome. It looks like `onclick="buttonClick(event)` is needed for it to work in both Firefox and Chrome.